# What tier for Challenges in Generations?

Tags: titanfall

(This is about the original Titanfall, not Titanfall 2) I have been playing Titanfall for quite a bit now, and I was wondering about reaching higher generations. I know you have to do challenges, but is it the first tier of the challenge (I) or do we have to go up to the highest tier of the challenge for it to count? Example: Top Gun(I) won't work because you have to get to Top Gun(V). I was just wondering how much I have to do the challenges.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember, it's all tiers of the challenges.
When you go to the regen challenges list, there's a button to toggle between show active and show all.  Showing all does show all tiers of the challenge.

It sounds like you haven't regenerated yet, so I'll say don't worry about it yet.  Each regeneration resets your challenges, so you can't start working on them until you regenerate.